# Batch Fuzzy String Queries in Rails/Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, fuzzy-search

I'm on rails 4.2, postgres 9.3.4, ruby 2.2.1.

I have a Merchant table. Each merchant has a name.  I regularly need to fuzzy match big lists of names (>500) to this merchant table.  I'm currently using [the fuzzily gem](https://github.com/mezis/fuzzily) for this.

However the gem only lets me fuzzy search for one possible match at a time.  This is way too slow for my application.

Is there a way, preferably using something built into postgres, to batch the queries so I can search for them all in one query?

Comment: That won't help much, I'm afraid. Fuzzy match is a quite complex operation as-is. You might need to redesign that part.

Comment: You can load the 500 records into a table and use a join on a fuzzy match condition.  The performance probably will not improve much, but it would only be one query.

Comment: Firstly, why is fuzzy matching a regular need? Secondly, why not store matches in a secondary table and put an index on that? For example, if someone regularly misspells Marrakesh, store the misspelling with the ID(s) of matching record(s).